multiple modifiers in BEM
I have component button
<button type="button" className="button button_size_large button_color_primary button_type_fill">
    <Icon className="button__icon" type={'bc-icon-info'} disabled={false} isFilled={true} />
    <span className="button__text">Button</span>
</button>

each of modifiers changes

button_color_primary

button_type_fill
button_type_outline
button_type_text


button_color_secondary

button_type_fill
button_type_outline
button_type_text


button_color_danger

button_type_fill
button_type_outline
button_type_text



and so on ...
In scss i have created this
    &_color_primary {
        &.button_type_fill {
            &:hover {}
            &:focus {}
            &:active {}
            &:disabled {}
            .button__text { }
            .button__icon { }
        }
        &.button_type_outline {
            &:hover {}
            &:focus {}
            &:active {}
            &:disabled {}
            .button__text { }
            .button__icon { }
        }
        &.button_type_text {
            &:hover {}
            &:focus {}
            &:active {}
            &:disabled {}
            .button__text { }
            .button__icon { }
        }
    }


And this way for _secondary , _danger.
I think this is not good approach. Please provide your suggestions .

You can set global style for global selector like button_type_fill and then only set color in variant like button_color_primary

This is not BEM approach.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
